# Moved AD domain controller on RHEL 6, ssh not working

Tags: ssh, kerberos, samba, rhel6

I use samba on RHEL6 to control and active directory single sign-on to a windows 2003 server.  Kerberos is used behind the scenes to control access to samba share and to handle ssh logins.  Everything was working just fine.

Windows admins then created a new 2008 server (new domain, new IP) and asked me to link up with this one instead (all users were migrated).  I figured it was a simple matter of editing /etc/samba/smb.conf, /etc/ssh/ssh_config, and /etc/krb5.conf and adding entries for the new server to make everything transfer smoothly.

I can connect to the samba share so I know authentication through kerberos is generally working.  However, I can't log in through ssh anymore.  When I enter the correct password the SSH client terminates (if you enter wrong password, it just returns access denied as expected).  KRB log files indicate a general authentication error - but that seems unlikely to me since samba works (also, I had no problem with the "net ads join").

Is it possible that there is something cached relating to the old server that needs to be reset in order to get the login working again?  I can login just fine from the console - so it seems related to SSH.

Comment: Just a guess; Is "GSSAPIAuthentication" set to "yes" in your sshd_config? If so, try setting it to "no" and restarting sshd. Assuming your console login uses the same PAM modules as your ssh login, the GSSAPI may be conflicting with them somehow.

Comment: Turned out I didn't remember to update the "/etc/ssh.allow" file.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I didn't remember to update the "/etc/ssh.allow" file.